# Converting multiple optional values in Scala

Tags: scala, type-conversion, option-type

I am writing a function that receives several optional `String` values and converts each one to either an `Int` or a `Boolean` and then passes the converted values to `Unit` functions for further processing. If any conversion fails, the entire function should fail with an error. If all conversions succeed, the function should process the converted values and return a success.

Here is the function I have written (simplified from the actual):

```
f(x: Option[String], y: Option[String], z: Option[String]): Result = {
  val convertX = x.map(value => Try(value.toInt))
  val convertY = y.map(value => Try(value.toBoolean))
  val convertZ = z.map(value => Try(value.toBoolean))

  val failuresExist =
    List(convertX, convertY, convertZ).flatten.exists(_.isFailure)

  if (failuresExist) BadRequest("Cannot convert input")
  else {
    convertX.foreach {
      case Success(value) => processX(value)
      case _ =>
    }

    convertY.foreach {
      case Success(value) => processY(value)
      case _ =>
    }

    convertZ.foreach {
      case Success(value) => processZ(value)
      case _ =>
    }

    Ok()
  }
}
```

Although this solution will probably work, it is very awkward. How can I improve it?

Comment: For working, potentially improvable codes I think a better place is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ In case it does not work, could you explain what is the problem in your opinion?

Comment: @GáborBakos This is a fairly specific question about what seems to be a missing method. I think it's fine here.

Comment: I case it is not obvious, I am writing a controller for a Play application. There are (currently) 3 optional query parameters that I need to process. I would rather do them all in one call since they are related.

Answer (score 0):

For completence I am adding the a piece of code here that process the values are required. However if this is better than that the original is debatable. If you want to process all the value and gather the results of the transformation [scalaz Validator](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html) could be a better option.

```
import scala.util.Try

val x = Some("12")
val y = Some("false")
val z = Some("hello")

def process(v: Boolean) = println(s"got a $v")
def processx(v: Int) = println(s"got a number $v")

// Abstract the conversion to the appropriate mapping
def mapper[A, B](v: Option[String])(mapping: String => A)(func: Try[A] => B) = for {
    cx <- v.map(vv => Try(mapping(vv)))
  } yield func(cx)

def f(x: Option[String], y: Option[String], z: Option[String]) = {
  //partially apply the function here. We will use that method twice.
  def cx[B] = mapper[Int, B](x)(_.toInt) _
  def cy[B] = mapper[Boolean, B](y)(_.toBoolean) _
  def cz[B] = mapper[Boolean, B](z)(_.toBoolean) _

  //if one of the values is a failure then return the BadRequest, 
  // else process each value and return ok
  (for {
    vx <- cx(_.isFailure)
    vy <- cy(_.isFailure)
    vz <- cz(_.isFailure)
    if vx || vy || vz
  } yield {
    "BadRequest Cannot convert input"
  }) getOrElse {
    cx(_.map(processx))
    cy(_.map(process))
    cz(_.map(process))
    "OK"
  }

}
f(x,y,z)
```

In the case a "short circuit" behaviour is required the following code will work.

```
import scala.util.Try

val x = Some("12")
val y = Some("false")
val z = Some("hello")


def process(v: Boolean) = println(s"got a $v")
def processx(v: Int) = println(s"got a number $v")

def f(x: Option[String], y: Option[String], z: Option[String]) =
  (for {
     cx <- x.map(v => Try(v.toInt))
     cy <- y.map(v => Try(v.toBoolean))
     cz <- z.map(v => Try(v.toBoolean))
  } yield {
     val lst = List(cx, cy, cz)
      lst.exists(_.isFailure) match {
       case true => "BadRequest Cannot convert input"
       case _ =>
          cx.map(processx)
          cy.map(process)
          cz.map(process)
          "OK"
      }
  }) getOrElse "Bad Request: missing values"

f(x,y,z)
```

Comment: I do not believe it will work, because it will flag missing (optional) values as an error.

Answer (score 0):

A more imperative style could work, if you don't mind that.

```
def f(x: Option[String], y: Option[String], z: Option[String]): Result = {
    try {
        val convertX = x.map(_.toInt)
        val convertY = y.map(_.toBoolean)
        val convertZ = z.map(_.toBoolean)
        convertX.foreach(processX)
        convertY.foreach(processY)
        convertZ.foreach(processZ)
        Ok()
    } catch {
        case _: IllegalArgumentException | _: NumberFormatException => BadRequest("Cannot convert input")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using scalaz I would use the Option applicative and ApplicativeBuilder's `|@|` combinator. If any of the inputs are `None`, then the result is also `None`.

```
import scalaz.std.option.optionInstance
import scalaz.syntax.apply._
val result: Option[String] =
  Some(1) |@| Some("a") |@| Some(true) apply {
    (int, str, bool) =>
      s"int is $int, str is $str, bool is $bool"
  }
```

In pure scala, you could use `flatMap` on option:

```
val result: Option[String] =
  for {
    a <- aOpt
    b <- bOpt
    c <- cOpt
  } yield s"$a $b $c"
```

I personally prefer the applicative because it makes it clear that the results are independent. for-blocks read to me like "first do this with a, then this with b, then this with c" whereas applicative style is more like "with all of a, b, and c, do ..."

Another option with scalaz is `sequence`, which inverts a structure like `T[A[X]]` into `A[T[X]]` for traversable T and applicative A.

```
import scalaz.std.option.optionInstance
import scalaz.std.list.listInstance
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._
val list: List[Option[Int]] = List(Option(1), Option(4), Option(5))
val result: Option[List[Int]] = list.sequence
// Some(List(1, 4, 5))
```